# If I buy Pages from the Mac OS app store, do I then have to buy it again in the iOS store?

Tags: macos, ios, mac-appstore, ios-appstore

I'd like to not have to buy it twice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you do. They are two entirely separate apps for two radically different devices.

Comment: What a scam. I'll stick with open source.

Comment: It's not a scam. Do you expect the vendor of a Windows app to give you the Mac version for free or vice-versa?

Comment: @CajunLuke As it happens, Microsoft and Adobe _do_ give you both Mac and Windows versions of their flagship software for the same subscription price.

Comment: And Apple also happens to give away Pages for free with the purchase of a new Mac or iOS device. Individual examples don't mean that it's something we should expect all the time from everybody.

Answer (score 1):

OS X and iOS are two different operating systems so it doesn't work. The one for the iPad is a simpler (smaller file) than the one for the mac. So yes you need to buy a copy for your mac and another for your iPhone/ipad.